# matlab transposing & sorting in embedded IF statements

Tags: matlab

I've been stumped trying to create an if,else loop that transposes the following:

```
Subject: Date: Result:
AAA 02/01/12 10
AAA 02/02/12 12
AAA 02/03/12 14
BBB 02/01/12 25
BBB 02/02/12 26
BBB 02/03/12 27
CCC 01/01/12 66
CCC 01/02/12 70
CCC 01/03/12 75
```

I desire the information to be transposed across columns as depicted below:

```
SUBJECT 01/01/12 01/02/12 01/03/12 02/01/12 02/02/12 02/03/12
AAA RESULT
BBB RESULT
CCC RESULT
```

There should only be one date per column and one subject per row. The result will match its respective subject and placed in its appropriate cell. The data can consist anywhere from a few subject to thousands of subjects, dates, and results. Some results may consist of non numerical values (NaN). Also, the subjects and dates may me in any random order and subjects may consist of numeric and string characters.

UPDATE
@amro & superbest

If I had a text file with the date format:800317==mar/17/1980, 
How would I import this and modify the codes you've written? 
THanks again.

Comment: Your result depiction is a bit unclear, are you just trying to make a sparse matrix where the rows represent subjects and the columns are dates? It would help if you completed your above desired output, i.e. don't just put RESULT but rather put the numeric values in the correct places for the example you gave.

Comment: @BernardUntalanJr: and how is this data stored: a cell array, a dataset object ?

Comment: Is this a text file, char matrix, cell array, or cell array of strings (each line as its own string) ? Another issue is that `RESULT` does not give a clue what you want there, there are several `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC` lines in your example data, each with their different results, but only one `RESULT` for each of `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC` in your desired output. Also, the order of dates in your example data and desired output does not seem consistent to me. Do you want to sort the dates? If yes, do you have DD/MM/YY, YY/MM/DD, MM/DD/YY or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script which should do what you want:

```
% Clean up
clc
clear

% Hardcoded example input
input = {
    'AAA'    '02/01/12'    10
    'AAA'    '02/02/12'    12
    'AAA'    '02/03/12'    14
    'BBB'    '02/01/12'    25
    'BBB'    '02/02/12'    26
    'BBB'    '02/03/12'    27
    'CCC'    '01/01/12'    66
    'CCC'    '01/02/12'    70
    'CCC'    '01/03/12'    75
    };

% Figure out how many rows and columns there will be
header_row = unique(input(:, 2));
header_col = unique(input(:, 1));

% Pre-allocation for better performance
output = cell(length(header_col), length(header_row));

% Rearrange the array
for i = 1:size(input, 1)
    % Find to which date and subject this element belongs
    subject = find(strcmp(header_col, input{i, 1}));
    date = find(strcmp(header_row, input{i, 2}));

    % Put the value in the appropriate slot
    output{subject, date} = input{i, 3};
end

% Add header columns and rows and print the result
result = [['SUBJECT' header_row']; [header_col output]];
```

Comment: As an aside, you may like `home` instead of `clc`.  `home` gets you a clean command window but keeps the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the data stored in a [dataset array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/datasetclass.html) object, then the [unstack](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/dataset.unstack.html) method is what you are looking for (sometimes referred to as tall-to-wide conversion).

---

I worked out a simple example that shows how to do this without the dataset class:

```
%# cell array: subjects, dates, values
data = {
    'AA' '2012-05-01' 0.1
    'AA' '2012-05-03' 0.2
    'BB' '2012-05-02' 0.3
    'CC' '2012-05-01' 0.4
    'CC' '2012-05-02' 0.5
    'CC' '2012-05-03' 0.6
};

[subjects,~,subjectsMap] = unique(data(:,1));
[dates,~,datesMap] = unique(data(:,2));
M = nan(numel(subjects),numel(dates));
for i=1:numel(subjects)
    %# get all rows with subject == subject_i
    rIdx = (subjectsMap == i);
    %# fill values at this row for the specified columns
    M(i,datesMap(rIdx)) = cell2mat(data(rIdx,3));
end

D = cell(size(M)+1);
D(2:end,2:end) = num2cell(M);       %# fill values
D(1,2:end) = dates;                 %# column headers
D(2:end,1) = subjects;              %# row headers
```

and here is the data before (tall) and after (wide) the conversion:

```
>> data
data = 
    'AA'    '2012-05-01'    [0.1]
    'AA'    '2012-05-03'    [0.2]
    'BB'    '2012-05-02'    [0.3]
    'CC'    '2012-05-01'    [0.4]
    'CC'    '2012-05-02'    [0.5]
    'CC'    '2012-05-03'    [0.6]

>> D
D = 
      []    '2012-05-01'    '2012-05-02'    '2012-05-03'
    'AA'    [       0.1]    [       NaN]    [       0.2]
    'BB'    [       NaN]    [       0.3]    [       NaN]
    'CC'    [       0.4]    [       0.5]    [       0.6]
```